# Sending an email from FormSubmit API

Tags: ajax

I need to change the "from" and "Subject" email fields, when I have to use the FormSubmit API.

The API always uses the "FormSubmit" text in the "from" email field and "Someone just submitted your form on http://localhost:5500/." text in the "subject" email field.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about https://formsubmit.co/ API. The documentation mentions

https://formsubmit.co/documentation

_subject:

This value is used for the email's subject, so that you can quickly reply to submissions without having to edit the subject line each time.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Whatever subject you want to provide">
```